# Bootstrap 4 collapse transition not working with col-2 class

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Through Bootstrap 4 and HTML 5, I'm attempting to make a Bootstrap column collapsible, with a nice transition, on the click of a button. I'm utilizing the Bootstrap collapse component described here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/.

By default, this collapses my div column vertically. To achieve a horizontal collapse transition, I've added some CSS.

I was able to recreate my issue through the following snippet:

```css
.collapse { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
.collapse.show {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
.collapsing {
    position: relative;
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
    transition-property: height, visibility;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
    transition-duration: 0.35s;  
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    }
.collapsing.width {-webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
    transition-property: width, visibility;
    width: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div id="left-column" class="col-2 p-0 m-0 collapse show width">
      <div style="Background: #6d7fcc;">
      This should transition
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <a href='#' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#left-column">
      Click here to transition
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above, the element does get hidden; however, there is no transition at all. I found out after many frustrating minutes that I am able to achieve my dream of transitioning horizontally by removing the "col-2" class from the left column div being collapsed as shown here:

```css
.collapse { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
.collapse.show {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
.collapsing {
    position: relative;
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
    transition-property: height, visibility;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
    transition-duration: 0.35s;  
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    }
.collapsing.width {-webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
    transition-property: width, visibility;
    width: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div id="left-column" class="p-0 m-0 collapse show width">
      <div style="Background: #6d7fcc;">
      This should transition
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <a href='#' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#left-column">
      Click here to transition
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the reasoning behind this? How do I implement this horizontal transition, while keeping true to the bootstrap grid system?